# General sibling selector - odd behavior

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

As far as I understand the general sibling selector in CSS selects the descending siblings of an element.

Consider the following code:

```
<head>
<style>
h3 ~ div {
    color: #FF00FF;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Header 3</h3>
    <div>Sibling divivion</div>
    <p>
        <p>Nested paragraph</p>
        <div>Nested division</div>
    </p>
</body>
```

I would expect the general sibling selector to target all descending siblings of h3 that are div elements.

Can someone explain why the "Nested division" is selected? I don't think it is a sibling of h3?

Comment: BTW, I would not use the term "descending siblings" to avoid possible misunderstandings; it would be more normal to say "following siblings".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `div` actually is a sibling of the `h3` element. You can't have a `p` element and a `div` element inside a `p` element:

> "The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level
>   elements (including P itself)."

Reference: [9.3.1 Paragraphs: the P element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)

When the browser encounters the second paragraph, it will end the first paragraph, so the second paragraph and the `div` element ends up after the first paragraph:

```
<h3>Header 3</h3>
<div>Sibling divivion</div>
<p></p>
<p>Nested paragraph</p>
<div>Nested division</div>
<p></p>
```

The ending tag for the paragraph is optional, so a paragraph ends either with an ending tag, or where the next block element starts. The intended closing tag for the first paragraph is missing a starting tag, and ends up as a separate paragraph.

Comment: Oh snap, just posted the same. +1

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your time and explanation.